# Have to send text to focus textbox of other application

Tags: c#, sendmessage, intptr

I spent many days for sending text value to focused textbox of other application in C#.

**My code:**

```
IntPtr txtLot = FindWindowEx(orderdialog, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);

SendMessage(txtLot, WM_SETTEXT, 0, lot.ToString());
```

I want any one solution of my two choice.

**Choice 1:**
There are three edit controls that I found in spy++. In the Above code, I got only 1st edit control. But I need to get IntPtr of 2nd edit control value to send some string.

**Choice 2:**
We can use tab key to focus the 2nd edit control. In that, 2nd control is focused but I can't able to send string. Because I don't know the **IntPtr** of focused control textbox. How to get the IntPtr of focused control.

Please suggest me which choice is suitable.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all controls using the second parameter of `FindWindowEx` method.

According to the MSDN:

> hwndChildAfter [in, optional]
>
> Type: HWND
>
> A handle to a child window.
>
> The search begins with the next child window in the Z order. The child
>   window must be a direct child window of hwndParent, not just a
>   descendant window. If hwndChildAfter is NULL, the search begins with
>   the first child window of hwndParent.

So you can use simple loop:

```
IntPtr fromHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
while (true) 
{
    IntPtr txtLot = FindWindowEx(orderdialog, fromHandle, "Edit", null);
    if (txtLot == IntPtr.Zero) break; // not found
    if (/*check if control satisfy some conditions*/) {
        SendMessage(txtLot, WM_SETTEXT, 0, lot.ToString());
    }
    fromHandle = txtLot;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the above code is same as my code. "orderdialog" has 3 edit control, if we use this "FindWindowEx(orderdialog, fromHandle, "Edit", null);", it will get only the 1st edit control. I want 2nd edit control. **For Ex**: txtlot is 1st edit control and txtprice is 2nd edit control. I want is txtprice 2nd edit control.

Comment: No, it's not the same. It will iterate through ALL your textboxes. I've specially mentioned the second parameter. We are changing `fromHandle` in the loop (setting to current found control) so next `FindWindowEx` call will find next textbox. It's a slightly modified working example from my old project.

Comment: I will try.. Any possibilities of choice 2. How to get the IntPtr of focused textbox control.

Comment: Tou can find focused control hwnd using `GetFocus()` API call: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getfocus